# Upload Complete project on Nexus

Tags: android, nexus

My code from gradle:

```
task sourcesZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'sources'
}
```

I have done this in my gradle but it uploads only .java files. How can I upload complete project that should contain res folder, setting.jar, gradle files? The project on importing to Android Studio should successfully be imported.
Currently it is giving "settings.jar not found" error.

To be specific how can I create a zip including everything

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the project or artifacts after building it using shell scripts and then upload the zip file to nexus.